# python server: localhost: Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I have placed d3.js file in a local folder.
I have launched a python server

```
python -m http.server 8888 &
```

and then tried to open the file index.html in three different browsers, Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

The file loads the javscript code in Edge but not in Chrome and Firefox.

I also tried to open the index.html file directly (by typing in the location rather than doing localhost:8888 in the three browsers.

This time the javascript loaded in Edge as well as Chrome. But not in Firefox.

How do I get the javascript to load in Chrome with the python http server?

How do I get it to load in Firefox with either of the methods (python http server or directly opening the file)?

index.html file below as asked for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Page Template</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="C:/Users/test/OneDrive/Documents/d3js/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var dataset=[5,10,15,20,25]
   d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("p")
   //.text("New paragraph!")
  .text(function (d) {return d;})
  .style("color","red")
  </script>
 this is a test
</html>
```

Comment: Let's see the html file. Also need to makes sure I understand what _**open the file index.html**_ really means. Do you mean you open the web browser and type `http://localhost:8888` in to the address bar and hit enter, or do you mean you use the file browser and double click the `index.html` file there?

Comment: both methods. both work in Edge. double click works in Edge and Chrome. Nothing works in Firefox.